# Convertir secuencia de texto en un array c#

Tags: c#

Hola bueno tengo una duda de cómo hacer que una variable string lo convierta a un arreglo de números. Por ejemplo:

String aux = "5,78,92,11,9,75,1,8."
A algo así
int[] num = {5,78,92,11,9,75,1,8}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la funcion `split` de `c#` el cual solo le indicas el separador de cadena

Ejemplo:

```
String aux = "5,78,92,11,9,75,1,8.";
string[] num = aux.Split(',');
```

convertir a una lista de entero

```
var num=aux.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

array de enteros

```
int[] num = aux.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```